# Visual Studio Code for macOS syntax error only for React Native 0.61

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

[image]

This behaviour occurs when I add folder to workspace (React Native 0.61 created from npx react-native init ...)

No any issues with the previous version (0.60).

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In this case, I managed to solve by hover an error then select **Quick Fix** and **Fix all prettier/prettier problems**